# How to ask if two variables are equal to something in one if statement

Tags: int

What I'm trying to do is make an if statement asking to check that two separate int variables equal a certain number, and if they don't, run a piece of code.

E.g.

```
int x = 10;
int y = 10;

if((x && y) != 9)
  //do something
```

Please help me out

Comment: Please tag your question with the programming language you are using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possible in one `if` statement, but not with only one binary condition; you have to compare each variable separately, and connect both comparison results with a logical AND (`&&`):

```
if ((x != 9) && (y != 9)) …
```

**P.S.:** The above assumes that you only want to do something (`…`) if *both* variables have some value other than 9. If you want to do something even if just one of the variables is not equal to 9, then replace the logical AND (`&&`) with logical OR (`||`):

```
if ((x != 9) || (y != 9)) …
```

Comment: I put them there intentionally, to highlight the number of operations involved as well as their order of evaluation.

Comment: @William: If you find this answer helpful or if it even solved your issue, then feel free to accept the answer (click on the tick mark next to it).